# Ninject.MVC3 invalid path to NinjectWebCommon.cs

Tags: ninject, ninject.web.mvc, ninject-extensions

I'm using the Ninject.MVC3 in my application and it has been working great until I desided to rename my solution/projects. Everything has been renamed correctly and all tests passes and so on. The one thing that does not work is the generated `NinjectWebCommon` class.

This line:

`bootstrapper.Initialize(CreateKernel);`

Throws this exception:

`System.InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains no elements`

When I look at the "yellow screen of death" I see that the source file of `NinjectWebCommon.cs` is totally wrong. It's the path that was accurate before the projects got renamed.

I've checked all paths in the .proj files and can't find any error there. I've also tried to throw away the app_start folder and re-installing the nuget packages.

Any suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally solved this one by clearing the web site cache:

`%LocalAppData%\Microsoft\WebsiteCache`